# How to implement 'open file location' behaviour programmatically (c++ builder)

Tags: windows, filesystems, c++builder

In Windows Media Player you can right click on a music file and click 'open file location' and it opens an explorer window with the file selected.

I want to be able to do this in applications.  So given a filename (as an ansi string) I want to be able to go to the file in a new explorer window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try launching explorer.exe with option **/select,`<`selected file path`>`**. Something like:

```
explorer /n, /select,c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

It should open new explorer window with **c:\windows** folder open and **notepad.exe** selected.

Comment: can I run this using shellexecute()?  I can run it on the command line and it works, but when I run in shellexecute nothing happens. 
ShellExecute(Form1->Handle,NULL,String("explorer.exe /n, /select," + FileName).c_str(),NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Comment: OK I'm tearing my hair out trying to run that in an application so I guess I'll ask a fresh question on stackoverflow.

Comment: What about: ShellExecute(Form1->Handle,"open","c:\\windows\\explorer.exe",  String("/n, /select," + FileName).c_str(),NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
Or use one of _spawn functions. See documentation for more.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) function.  Something like this should work:

```
ShellExecute(handle, "explore", @"C:\WINDOWS", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: I think that only works for folders, not files.  I want to explore _and_ select the file.

Comment: I figured out the command line for this... explorer /select,(filename) so I now need to figure out how to run that shell command

Answer (score 0):

It's a Win2 FAQ for more than 16 years (!)

Search on Google Groups before posting a so basic question where the C code has been posted 25000 times...